# How do I upgrade the PHP in RAD PHP XE2

Tags: php, ide, radphp

I am using RADPHP XE2 (from Borland / Embarcadero) as my IDE.  Only because I have been using their IDE for years.  I am not actuially using any of the VCL components, as that is a stupid concept for web-design.

I want to upgrade the PHP that it is using.  I have installed the latest PHP outside the IDE and it runs.  But the IDE still uses 5.2.  Is it possible to coax it to use the new one ?  Any ideas anyone ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**At the Moment RadPHP XE2 Update4 supports PHP 5.2.14**.
Tired to integrate PHP 5.3 and PHP 5.4 on myself.

Generally after modifying the php.ini-dist File and integrating the correct `xdebug` Library tried to Debug Type3 with PHP 5.3 the Debugger starts but after the first to or three Breakpoints it hangs.

Comment: Might have to go to Eclipse then

Comment: what is your main purpose?? if you want php IDE try phpstorm. I'm using it. or else can move to eclipse

Comment: I am not using the vcl, thats an idiotic concept for html.  I am using it only because I have been using Borland IDEs since they went into business and I know my way around them.

Comment: @RohitGupta sad thing is they doesn't have latest php update. Sorry to tell about

Answer (score 2):

Abstract: Download link and fix list for RadPHP XE2 Update 4

RadPHP XE2 Update 4 is now available at http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/28759.

Comment: I am already on update 4, thanks.  Its actually been out for a while.